# CAShapeLayer, animating path with Transactions

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, cgpath, ios-animations

I wondering why when I try to animate the `path` property of a `CAShapeLayer`with a basic animation it works but when I try to do it with transaction it doesn't.

I've successfully animated other `animatable` properties using just transaction. Here is my current code:

```
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.0)
        path = scalePath() // a scaled version of the original path
    CATransaction.commit()
```

the new path is obtained scaling the original path with this (very hardcoded) function inside an extension of `CAShapeLayer`:

```
func scalePath()->CGPath{
    var scaleTransform =  CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: -150, y: -150)
    scaleTransform = scaleTransform.scaledBy(x: 10, y: 10)
    let newPath = path?.copy(using: &scaleTransform)

    return newPath!
}
```

Can you identify any issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple but a bit unsatisfactory: while the `path` property is animatable, it doesn't support **implicit** animations. This is called out in the Discussion section of [the documentation for the path property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521904-path):

> Unlike most animatable properties, `path` (as with all `CGPathRef` animatable properties) does not support implicit animation.

#### Explicit vs. Implicit animations

An "explicit" animation is an animation object (e.g. `CABasicAnimation`) that is *explicitly* added to the layer by calling `-addAnimation:forKey:` on the layer.

An "implicit" animation is an animation that happens *implicitly* as a result of changing an animatable property.

The animation is considered implicit even if the property is changed within a transaction.